# How to wait for a response from a function before doing something else in vuejs

Tags: vuejs2

I have an image upload function and this upload returns a data when finished, and I have a line below that function to do another task. the problem is vuejs/js does not wait until the first function completes the task. So, this is what my code looks like:

```
methods : {

    uploadImage (file) {

        this.uploadModule.upload(file); 

        if(this.uploadModule.isSuccess) {
             this.images.push(this.uploadModule.response)
        }

      // someFunction()
  }
}
```

So, in the above example since the upload() methods takes some time, then `someFunction()` part gets run before the `this.images.push()` part.

Is there away to just wait until the upload is finished before running another function?

Comment: This doesn't has much to do with vue, just a normal *how-to-async* problem. What you should do really depends on what the async `this.uploadModule.upload` does, and what it offers to execute code after the async operation finishes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can return a Promise from your upload method and execute the next portion of code as a callback in the "next" method of the Promise.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

It should look like this:

```
methods : {

  uploadImage (file) {

    this.uploadModule.upload(file).then(function () {
      if(this.uploadModule.isSuccess) {
        this.images.push(this.uploadModule.response)
      }

      // someFunction()
    })
  }
}
```

You can also handle your error using the Promise reject callback if the upload does not complete and handle the error with the catch method:

```
methods : {

  uploadImage (file) {

    this.uploadModule.upload(file).then(function () {
      this.images.push(this.uploadModule.response)
    }).catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error)
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm already using axios with then/catch methods inside the module ... so, I'm not sure if how this can be done further

Comment: @hidar Simply return the promise axios generates, like `return axios(...).then().catch()`, the function around this statement will return the promise, you can `upload().then()` outside the upload function, and the whole code will act as if you wrote `axios(...).then().catch().then(/*code in uploadImage*/)`

Comment: You're the HackerMaster !!